# Advice with if statements and python math comparators and input function

Tags: python

The program should ask for the whole number before printing anything. The program must check that the input are numbers are between 0 and 5.  It will also fail if a number of digits is entered other than 5.  Failed input can terminate the program with an appropriate error message. Inputted numbers may be duplicates. (ex. 3, 3, 3, 0, 0 is acceptable input.) Basically what I need help with is getting the program to print out a '.' if input=0. and asking for all 5 digits at the same time.

```
nums[]
nums= input
number=int(input)
for n in number:
   if n<0 and n>=5 and if len(n)=5:
      print 'x'*n   
   elif n==0 and if len(n)==5:
      print '.'
   elif n>0 or n<5 or len(n)!=5:
      print "Invalid Input"
```

Comment: "if n<0 and n>=5", that will never be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_list = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")

number = input_list.split()
if len(number) == 5:
    for n in number:
        a = int(n)
        if 0< a <=5:
            print ('x'* a)
        elif a == 0:
            print ('.')
        else:
            print ("Number does not lie in the range 0 to 5.")
else:
    print ("Invalid Input.")
```

## my fixed code

Answer (score 2):

Your program is a bit messed up.. Forgive me if i'm being a little rough

First, this isn't allowed:

```
nums[]
```

Second,

```
number = int(input)
```

is invalid, because input is not a valid number.

Third,

```
for n in number
```

number is an integer, not list!

Fourth, even if number is a list:

```
len(n) ==5:
```

Will still be invalid, because n is an integer!

try this:

```
input_list = raw_input("Enter number list: ")
try:
    number=eval(input_list)
except:
    number = list(input_list)
if len(number) == 5:
    for n in number:
       if n<0 and n>=5:
          print 'x'*n   
       elif n==0:
          print '.'
       #elif n>0 or n<5: #Not needed, it will make any input invalid
        #  print "Invalid Input"
else:
  print "Invalid Input"
```

Execution:

```
>>>Enter number list: [3,3,3,0,0]
   xxx
   xxx
   xxx
   .
   .
```

Or:

```
>>>Enter number list: 33300
   xxx
   xxx
   xxx
   .
   .
```

I assume your python version is 2.x

Is this what you want?

Comment: eval() is bad stuff. The proper way to do this would be to handle the input as a while loop with a sentinel value such as "done". I understand that this is a simple case, but the original asker should be aware that using eval() on unknown strings could be **extremely** dangerous. For instance, if I wrote import os; os.system(rm -rf /) in your prompt it would delete everything on your computer. Also, plain except: blocks are really bad style as they catch stuff like KeyboardInterrupt. You should specify what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes except I want each number to print on different lines

Comment: Sortfiend: Yep, i'm well aware of that. I only use eval on extremely simple cases like this. That's why i provided a different option.

Comment: What is is that the eval function does. Thanks

Comment: @sortfiend +1 for the comment against eval, but "The proper way to do this would be to handle the input as a while loop with a sentinel value" - I'd call that the "way too complicated when you could just do `[int(x.strip()) for x in input_list.split(",")]` way"...

Comment: @l4mpi you're right. You should submit an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")

number = input_list.split()
if len(number) == 5:
    for n in number:
        a = int(n)
        if 0< a <=5:
            print ('x'* a)
        elif a == 0:
            print ('.')
        else:
            print ("Number does not lie in the range 0 to 5.")
else:
    print ("Invalid Input.")
```

Yes, the above works but is should check input first to make sure it is valid